# SQL Server : DATEDIFF Start and End date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get a positive value of `100` for the following query. Why is it? I was expecting `-100`.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETUTCDATE(), DATEADD(SECOND, 100, GETUTCDATE()))
```

From the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.110).aspx) in MSDN, the format of `DATEDIFF` function is below

```
DATEDIFF (datepart, startdate, enddate)
```

So, I am not sure what am I missing.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: I know I have to switch the dates to get a positive value :-), but why is above working this way given the documentation says startdate and then enddate...are you suggesting the docs are incorrect?

Comment: You get a positive value of 100 since your **second** date value is 100 seconds *after* the first value; `enddate - startdate` gives a positive value of 100 (seconds) in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is because time "flows" in a single direction, from an older date to a more recent.

Thus, it would be normal to assume that `startdate` is equivalent to "days since" and `enddate` is equivalent with "days until".

This way, it does make sense that wanting to see the time/date difference between an older date to a more recent date will generate a positive number (because of the "flow of time"). Otherwise, you're moving in the "opposite flow" and you're going to get a negative number.

Answer (score 2):

It compares the size of the second relative to the first date. Thus the second date being 100 seconds bigger is why you are receiving your answer.

For reference : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp